# Manifest file shows 404. Not able to detect manifest under the service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

JSON file

manifiest.json

```
{
 "name": "Sample site",
 "short_name": "Site",
 "description": "Learn how to create and share something or other.",
 "start_url": "index.html",
 "background_color": "#000000",
 "theme_color": "#0f4a73",
 "icons": [{
   "src": "icon/icon-192x192.png",
   "sizes": "256x256",
   "type": "image/png"
 }]
}
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

Service-worker.js

```
const RESOURCES_TO_PRELOAD = [
'./',
'./index.html',
'./logo.svg',
'./register-worker.js',
'./todo-app.js',
'./manifest.json',
'./offline-404.html'
];
```

Manifest file shows 404. Not able to detect manifest under the service worker.

Any solution looking at the above code?

Answer (score 1):

The **web app manifest is a simple JSON file, whose extension should be .json,** looks like you have named the manifest file with extension .js and also in service worker you have used manifest.json file which is not available, as you have a manifest.js file. so the solution would be to change the extension to .json of the manifest file.

Comment: Although I didn't tried renaming it to .json, I too believe I must have made this silly mistake. thank you for pointing out.